# Electromagnetism Permeability of vacuum

Tags: electromagnetism, refraction, vacuum, polarization

How vacuum could have electromagnetism Permeability when there is no molecule in it.

(Permeability  of other medium get describe with effect of their polar or magnetic molecule)

Comment: Vacuum also has a refraction index, but doesn't refract. Same idea.

Comment: but refraction index is a compare between two thing not a real thing , electromagnetism Permeability is a property of something. we give refraction index = 1 to vacuum but Vacuum permeability = 4p * 10^-7 . it is something that measure independently .

Comment: It is not a measured value. It is just an assigned number. You can set it to 1 if you want (in some unit system).

Comment: put a winding (with no core) in vacuum ,i have I , N , L  so H is known , B is known  so μ = B/H. it is measured without my choice so there is something there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has to start with [Magnetization,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization) as it is a striking result of magnetism, and see how it is defined :

> In classical electromagnetism, magnetization or magnetic polarization is the vector field that expresses the density of permanent or induced magnetic dipole moments in a magnetic material. The origin of the magnetic moments responsible for magnetization can be either microscopic electric currents resulting from the motion of electrons in atoms, or the spin of the electrons or the nuclei. Net magnetization results from the response of a material to an external magnetic field. Paramagnetic materials have a weak induced magnetization in a magnetic field, which disappears when the magnetic field is removed. Ferromagnetic and ferrimagnetic materials have strong magnetization in a magnetic field, and can be magnetized to have magnetization in the absence of an external field, becoming a permanent magnet.

This is how the dipole moments enter , by Magnetization.

[Mathematically:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization#Relations_between_B,_H,_and_M)

$B=μ_0H+M$ in SI units

If there are no dipoles  (vacuum)  there is no Magnetization, so B and  H are proportional , and  $μ_0$  is the vacuum permeability

It is interesting to see the   [plots relating B and H proportionality relative to vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)):

[image: permeability]

If one wants to use $B=μH$ for materials , $μ$ defining the materials permeability, then one gets the confusion about dipoles.

Comment: thanks that M make it clear , the book I was reading did not mention that and I was confused what the ... is just happened there

Comment: "If there are no dipoles (vacuum) there is no Magnetization, so B and H are proportional..." Thats where I get confused. I mean if vacuum is just empty space and if there is nothing to be magnetised, why isnt B=H ?

Comment: @Jdeep   Why dont't you look at the answers in the duplicate which asks your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/542445/why-is-permeability-of-free-space-in-calculation-of-magnetic-field-a-non-zero

Answer (score 0):

If $\mu_0$ was zero then there would be no magnetic field due to moving charges in the vacuum. $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ just determine the strengths of electric and magnetic fields in a vacuum, as $\epsilon$ and $\mu$ do in a dielectric. A medium isn't needed for permeability, or else magnetic fields would be zero in the vacuum in many cases.

Comment: I understand this but when we wants to describe μ in a ferromagnetism (why and how μ work) we use the its molecule arrangement . I did not understand how in vacuum we could describe why  and how μ0 work?

Comment: @johnnyishere In a vacuum $mu_0$ is a constant. There's nothing to describe